# How to Cancel page navigation via JS

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a requirement ,say i have two pages, i am in second page and i have changed a text in the page and i clicked on first page link.I have to show the user my custom pop up  error message.Currently i can able to show my custom error message but the default error message from the web page like"Leave this page" or "stay here" is also coming with my pop up.

Here is the code i am using.

```
    function ExecuteCall(url) {
    try {
        var Result = ShowWarningPopUp();
        return Result;

    }
    catch (e) { }
}

window.onbeforeunload = onwindowclosing;
function onwindowclosing() {
   ExecuteCall("ExeOnClose.aspx");

}
```

in ShowWarningPopUp() i am checking the condition. Based on that condition , code will decide whether it need to do show pop up or not.My current outcome is i am getting the pop up and the page is posting back. Eventhough i am returning false the page is posting back to other page.Kindly show me a way to stop post back

Note: for displayinn the Pop up am using modal pop up extender.

Comment: This looks like a problem with event bubbling. Try attaching the handler using jQuery and inside call e.preventDefault();

Comment: you can't stop navigation in onbeforeunload, it's been dis-allowed. you could show the error message on the other page instead.